# list duplicate values in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates

i need to check for duplicate values that might occur in a dictionary. I have a dictionary in the following layout. Any advise is welcome! thanks so much

**the original dictionary**

```
dic = {'ab1': [{'ans': 'Male', 'val': '1'},
  {'ans': 'Female', 'val': '2'},
  {'ans': 'Other', 'val': '3'},
  {'ans': 'Prefer not to answer', 'val': '3'}],
 'bc1': [{'ans': 'Employed', 'val': '1'},
  {'ans': 'Unemployed', 'val': '2'},
  {'ans': 'Student', 'val': '3'},
  {'ans': 'Retired', 'val': '4'},
  {'ans': 'Part-time', 'val': '5'},
  {'ans': 'Prefer not to answer', 'val': '7'}],
 'bc2': [{'ans': 'Mother',
   'val': '1'},
  {'ans': 'Father ', 'val': '2'},
  {'ans': 'Brother', 'val': '3'},
  {'ans': 'Sister', 'val': '4'},
  {'ans': 'Grandmother', 'val': '4'},
  {'ans': 'Grandfather', 'val': '6'},
  {'ans': 'Son', 'val': '7'},
  {'ans': 'Daughter', 'val': '8'}]}
```

**the expected output** - a list that contains ONLY items with identical values per key - so only this

```
ab1: Other 3, Prefer not to answer 3
bc2: Sister 4, Grandmother 4
```

**code I have tried** it aims to reverse the dictionary first - but throws unhashable type list error i think because it treats it as a list when in fact the dict might be a tupple but i don't know how to change it

```
rev_dict = {}

for k, v in dic.items():
    rev_dict.setdefault(v, set()).add(k)
  
res = set(chain.from_iterable(v for k, v in rev_dict.items()
         if len(v) > 1))
```

Comment: Why do you need `pandas` tag here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not specified an exact output format, but since you tagged `pandas`, here's a `pandas` solution.

```
import pandas as pd
{k: pd.DataFrame(v)[lambda df: df['val'].duplicated(keep=False)].to_dict(orient='records') for k, v in dic.items()}
```

Output:

```
{
    'ab1': [{'ans': 'Other', 'val': '3'},
            {'ans': 'Prefer not to answer', 'val': '3'}],
    'bc1': [],
    'bc2': [{'ans': 'Sister', 'val': '4'}, {'ans': 'Grandmother', 'val': '4'}]
}
```

Comment: that is perfect thank you so much! exactly what I was looking for. I am just trying to understand the command so tried rewriting it in a long format with this 

`out=[]
for k, v in dic.items():
    print(k)
    i=pd.DataFrame(v)[lambda df: df['val'].duplicated(keep=False)].to_dict(orient='records')
    out.append(i) `

which outputs only the values, not the key (i.e. ab1, bc1, bc2). could you point out where i am going wrong here if you have time? thanks again

Comment: @br101 you are constructing a list with `out=[]`. Use `out = {}` (empty dict) and then `out[k] = i` instead of appending.

Answer (score 1):

The panda's answer is certainly nicer:

```
lst = []
for i in dic.keys():
    counts = Counter([j['val'] for j in dic[i]])
    new = {j['ans']: j['val'] for j in dic[i] if counts[j['val']] > 1}
    lst.append(i + ': ' + ', '.join(['{} {}'.format(i, new[i]) for i in new])) if new else None
```

Comment: thanks for your input but for me that is just returning a list of all key-value pairs like this. ['ab1: Male 1, Female 2, Other 3, Prefer not to answer 3',
 'bc1: Employed 1, Unemployed 2, Student 3, Retired 4, Part-time 5, Prefer not to answer 7',
 'bc2: Mother 1, Father  2, Brother 3, Sister 4, Grandmother 4, Grandfather 6, Son 7, Daughter 8']

Comment: `{j.get('ans'): j.get('val') for j in dic.get(i)} if j.get('val')>1}`?

Comment: @br101 Tx, updated to do the right thing, although there are better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Import itertools and try this:

```
list(itertools.chain(*[[(k, i['ans'],i['val']) for i in v] for k, v in dic.items()]))
```

Long version

```
import itertools

lst = []
for k,v in dic.items():
    
    for i in v:
        tup = (k, i['ans'],i['val'])
        
        lst.append(tup)

list(itertools.chain(*lst))
```

Comment: hi @PawanJain - this code prints all items in the dictionary, i want to print only cases where the val is duplicated per item - so the code should print only ```ab1: Other 3, Prefer not to answer 3
bc2: Sister 4, Grandmother 4``` but thank you for trying